# How to avoid content jump by add fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a sticky header on scroll. The only problem is that when I scroll down for `1000px`, the class `sticky` is added to the header and after that, there is a little jump of the content at the same moment when the class `sticky` is added to the header. I think this becomes, because header doesn't exists anymore on that place in the markup visually.

I tried to add a specific height to the header. Also wrap a div around `container`, so the `sub-header` stays on that place, but with no success. 
How should I fix this?

Live code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbaQvL?editors=110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the sticky activates you also need to set the margin-top of the about element equal to the height of the sticky.

It would be something like this:

```js
if (windowPos >= content) {
  $('#sub-header').addClass('sticky');
  $('#about').addClass('sticky-active');

} else {
  $('#sub-header').removeClass();
  $('#about').removeClass();
}
```

```css
#about.sticky-active {
  margin-top: 96px;
}
```

I made a working version codepen too. You can see it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeKVOJ).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. That's what I am searching for!

Answer (score 0):

Just add padding to body, when creating sticky header:

JS:

```
if (windowPos >= content) {
  $('#sub-header').addClass('sticky');
  $('body').addClass('sticked');
} else {
  $('#sub-header').removeClass();
  $('body').removeClass('sticked');
}
```

CSS:

```
body.sticked {
  padding-top: 96px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just give the header an absolute positioning during the scrolling:

```
...
#sub-header {
    position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
#sub-header, #sub-header.sticky {
    background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0; 
    z-index: 2000;
}
...
```

... and add a padding to your sections:

```
section {
  padding-top: 96px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZGxMZ